# SQL Server adding a Doc Breaks of paths to single delimited line

Tags: sql, sql-server

Every so often I do this using a combination of regex in textpad, and excel, but  if there is a programmatic approach in SQL, that would be more ideal, and I could start working on an automated query.

If given a CSV file of image paths with document breaks:

```
Doc,Path,DocBreak
Doc01,C:\Image\01.tif,Y
Doc02,C:\Image\02.tif,
Doc03,C:\Image\03.tif,
Doc04,C:\Image\04.tif,Y
Doc05,C:\Image\05.tif,
Doc06,C:\Image\06.tif,Y
```

I'm looking for an approach to get this kind of output where using the Y as the pattern, adds each path to a multi-delimited field, and loops that for each Y doc break:

```
Doc,Path
Doc01,C:\Image\01.tif|C:\Image\02.tif|C:\Image\03.tif 
Doc04,C:\Image\04.tif|C:\Image\05.tif
Doc06,C:\Image\06.tif
```

Is there a SQL function that would be useful for this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server MGMT studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your server version is SQL 2012 or above. You can use this,

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Doc VARCHAR(20), Path VARCHAR(20),DocBreak VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES
('Doc01','C:\Image\01.tif','Y'),
('Doc02','C:\Image\02.tif',NULL),
('Doc03','C:\Image\03.tif',NULL),
('Doc04','C:\Image\04.tif','Y'),
('Doc05','C:\Image\05.tif',NULL),
('Doc06','C:\Image\06.tif','Y')

;WITH T AS (

SELECT *, GRP = SUM(CASE WHEN DocBreak ='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY Doc)
FROM @Temp
)
SELECT T1.Doc, STUFF(X.Path,1,1,'') Path FROM T T1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT '|' + Path FROM T T2 WHERE T2.GRP = T1.GRP FOR XML PATH('') ) X (Path)
WHERE T1.DocBreak = 'Y'
```

Result:

```
Doc                  Path
-------------------- --------------------------------------------------------
Doc01                C:\Image\01.tif|C:\Image\02.tif|C:\Image\03.tif
Doc04                C:\Image\04.tif|C:\Image\05.tif
Doc06                C:\Image\06.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing a csv file string

**Example**

```
Declare @csv varchar(max) = '
Doc,Path,DocBreak
Doc01,C:\Image\01.tif,Y
Doc02,C:\Image\02.tif,
Doc03,C:\Image\03.tif,
Doc04,C:\Image\04.tif,Y
Doc05,C:\Image\05.tif,
Doc06,C:\Image\06.tif,Y
'

;with cte as (
        Select A.RetSeq
              ,B.*
              ,Grp = sum(case when B.Pos3='Y' then 1 else 0 end) over (Order by A.RetSeq)
         From (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                 From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@csv,char(13)+char(10),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                 Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
               ) A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                              ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                              ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.RetVal,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
                     ) B
         Where Pos2 is not null and Pos3<>'DocBreak'
) 
Select Top 1 with ties
       Doc  = Pos1
      ,Path =Stuff((Select Distinct '|' +Pos2 From cte Where Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From cte A
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition by Grp Order by RetSeq)
```

**Returns**

```
Doc     Path
Doc01   C:\Image\01.tif|C:\Image\02.tif|C:\Image\03.tif
Doc04   C:\Image\04.tif|C:\Image\05.tif
Doc06   C:\Image\06.tif
```